# Select string not to display file path/name

Tags: powershell

My select string looks like:

```
$prevdate = Get-Content "C:\Prevday.txt"
Select-String -Path "C:\latestdatetime.txt" -Pattern "$prevdate" | Measure-Latest | Out-File "C:\Prevday_snap.txt"
```

But the output which I am getting displayed is

```
C:\latestdatetime.txt:1:8/17/2015 9:18:45 AM
```

I don't want the part which has been styled as **Bold**. How can I get this done.?

Comment: btw, what's that 'measure-latest' doing? Is it a filter?

Comment: @AdilHindistan: Measure-Latest is a function for checking latest of all the one which are same. See here.. https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/measure-latest-finding-the-latest-date-time/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-String` returns `MatchInfo` objects.  The text of the matched line will be in the `Line` property of those objects.

```
Select-String -Path "C:\latestdatetime.txt" -Pattern "$prevdate" | Select -ExpandProperty Line
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question clearly but it sounds like you would like the value 'part' of select-string result, and not where it is found. If so, you need to go into the properties of the match object you get from select-string. For example:

```
PS C:\Users\Adil> 
gc C:\Temp\a.txt
$date = "10:34:31 AM"
select-string -path C:\temp\a.txt -Pattern $date | % {$_.matches.groups.value}




Tuesday, August 18, 2015 10:32:58 AM
Tuesday, August 17, 2015 10:34:31 AM
Tuesday, August 16, 2015 10:34:32 AM
Tuesday, August 18, 2015 10:34:31 PM
Tuesday, August 18, 2015 11:34:31 AM
Tuesday, August 18, 2015 12:34:31 AM
Tuesday, August 18, 2015 13:34:31 AM


10:34:31 AM
```